# Can authors of deleted comments be notified using the @reply syntax?

Tags: support, notifications, comment-replies

In [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) we learn that the @ syntax can be used to notify "authors, commenters, and editors" (and additionally mods who closed a question).

Does the list of "commenters" extend to "all those who've ever commented on the post" or just to "those whose comments are visible, i.e. not deleted"?

In other words, if I comment on a post and subsequently delete it (it being the only comment I have made on that post, and I am neither the author nor an editor of the post), and another user types `@Willie` in his comment, will I be notified?

Comment: If they can, I'd say this is a bug.

Comment: @Tim ManishEarth hello! as requested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133254/can-authors-of-deleted-comments-be-notified-using-the-reply-syntax#comment369534_133254) didn't work.

<s>Makes sense, since I recall reading that deleted comments leave no trace (unlike posts). They disappear. So any record of you having commented disappears as well--then the @reply won't work.</s>

Looks like comments *do* leave a diamond-visible trace, so I guess that they are stored in the database. But the SE people have already thought of this and made sure that @replies don't work.

Comment: Technically, they leave *some* kind of trace, because diamond moderators can [now] see deleted comments. But they can't be "undeleted", so they are still very different from deleted answers.

Comment: The comment by @TheEstablishment explains why I asked the question in the first place. (I mod Math.SE.) Good to know that the coding is "sensible". :) Ideally I would like to see this (minor) point added to the faq.

Comment: Well that's easy to do, @Willie. The [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) is a community wiki (as all Meta FAQ are), and people who have interesting tidbits to add are encouraged to edit it.

Comment: @TheEstablishment of course. It just feels a bit awkward since I am the one who asked this question and am a bit unsteady with the state of my knowledge; since this is something that is in the code, presumably someone with access to it can give a more definitive answer (than I can based on experimental inferences).

Comment: @WillieWong I can confirm that the code only considers current comments for `@reply` candidates; deleted comments are not considered. Tim has the truth of it.

Comment: @Willie: You'll be surprised at how much of that faq answer is based on experiments. I should know, look at the edit history `:-)` So go ahead and edit, please!

Comment: @all okay. Done!

Comment: Ironically, `@all` does not do anything. :-)

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Except summon ME